# Check If A Command By A Specific User Is In Progress Discord.py Rewrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So, I was making a discord bot command, basically a game of rock paper scissors (2 users).
I was stuck at a thing for a lot of time. The thing is .. **if a user (first person) is already running a game with a mentioned user (second user) and the game is in progress, then a third person uses the command mentioning either the first or the second person, the commands shouldn't work**. But I am unable to figure this thing out. I guess code chunk isn't really necessary in this situation, but if it is needed please just tell me. Also, I wasn't able to figure out how to use **two `wait_for()` together**. Any help is appreciated!

Also, Idk if this will affect the question but **Inputs Are Taken In User DMs**

Comment: It is probably the best solution to store the ongoing matches on your end (e.g. in a database or a file of sorts) and check from there if the mentioned user is already in a match

Comment: damn i guess i knew it .. but I really forgot it when needed..thanks for reminding me I will try to do it ..thanks @LukasThaler

Comment: You're looking for [`commands.max_concurrency`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.max_concurrency)

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I guess this would just add a limit to command...and I don't really want a command to be limited....I just wanted that if a certain person is in-game he  cant start a game with him but can start with others who are not in-game.....and as mentioned the solution by `Lukas Thaler` worked well ..still thanks for the time and max_concurreny now might help me in some other field